# Trying to check to see if my MVC model's value is equal to NULL in my database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, json

Here's the code (please disregard the `<p>` tags in my `<td>`, this is just for testing:
[image]

Right now, I have `NULL` in my SQL Server database for `EarlyDod`:

[image]

The error I'm getting when comparing `item.EarlyDod` and `DBNull.Value` is:
[image]

I understand this error, and it makes sense, but when I have a `NULL` value in my database (which I would imagine is `DBNull.Value` no?), how do I compare my C# object's value `item.EarlyDod` to check if it's NULL in the database?  The value that's coming back from the database via my WebAPI (in JSON format) for `EarlyDod` is "0001-01-01T00:00:00", not some sort of NULL value, even though it's NULL as you can see in the database.

Comment: Where do you pull from the database?  `item.EarlyDod` doesn't appear to be a nullable datetime anyways

Comment: It looks like item is an entity and if so you should compare the property with null. However the error seems to say that the property type is of DateTime and that could suggest that your mapping is set to DateTime instead of Nullable<DateTime>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DateTime` is not nullable.  So when you are pulling it, it's instantiating the default value for DateTime (`DateTime.MinValue`)

So you can either convert `item.EarlyDod` to `DateTime?`, and use

```
item.EarlyDod != null
```

or keep it as a DateTime and simply replace

```
item.EarlyDod != DBNull.Value
```

with

```
item.EarlyDod != DateTime.MinValue
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a shot.  Appreciate it